# can not compile custom bootstrap 4 file with gulp sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp, bootstrap-4, gulp-watch

i'm trying to change the primary color without affecting the source, so in the included _custom file I add the variable with the color i want but when i compile, the color stays the same. I'm compiling with Gulp. I'm going by the [docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/options/) yet don't understand what it means by using  `$enable-*`. Any help would be awesome

Within my _custom.scss file

```
$blue:   #4da6ea;
```

**my gulp task**

```
gulp.task('watchSass', () => {
    gulp.watch('./assets/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist/scss/**/*.scss', ['compile-bootstrap-sass']);
});
```

I've also tried sass --watch command on the bootstrap.scss, it's all connected but doesn't seem to compile and add on my custom file

Comment: found it, i just moved the order of the _custom in the boostrap.scss to the first, above _variables.scss

import "custom"; 
import "variables";